# regular expression for given pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need two regular expressions, on that matches anything that ends with `10PL` that is `(a single whitespace) (any integer) (the string PL in caps) (line terminates)`. I tried the following but none of them works. For eg.

```
var str="Visit W3Schools 45PL";  // should match this
var str1="Visit W3Schools 45PL Other";  // should NOT match this
var str2 = "Any Random value 133PL" // should match this
var str3 = "Any Random value 133Pl" // should NOT match this
```

The other should match `21.323X230` `(a single whitespace) (any floating value) (the word X in caps) (any other floating point value) (line terminates)`. For eg.

```
var test="Visit W3Schools 4X5";  // should match this
var test1="Visit W3Schools 4X5PL Other";  // should NOT match this
var test2 = "Any Random value 13.270X46.96" // should match this
var test3 = "Any Random value 13.21X12.36 " // should NOT match this, as last word is white space
```

I tried the following pattern (for the first one (the PL one)).

```
var patt1=/\s+\d+/PL/g;
var patt2 = /[ ]+[0-9]+/PL/g;
document.write(patt1.test(str));
document.write(patt2.test(str));
document.write(patt1.test(str1));
document.write(patt2.test(str1));
document.write(patt1.test(str2));
document.write(patt2.test(str2));
document.write(patt1.test(str3));
document.write(patt2.test(str3));
```

result was all null (document.write didn't wrote anything). So, can anyone help me figure out regex for these two patterns?

Comment: [this might be helpful](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your pattern - the `/` in the middle of the regex is

- not needed (there is no literal slash you want to match, is there?), and
- confusing to the regex engine because it interprets it as the ending regex delimiter. It then tries to interpret `PL/g` as regex modifiers (which of course doesn't work).

Also, you're not telling the regex that it should match that pattern only at the end of a line. So try this:

```
var patt1 = / \d+PL$/gm;
```

`$` matches (together with the `m` modifier) the end of a line. Without that modifier, it would only match the end of the string.

For the second one:

```
var patt2 = / \d+(?:\.\d+)?X\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/gm;
```

Also, please don't `visit W3Schools`. It's one of the most error-ridden places on the internet. If you don't believe me, check out http://w3fools.com.

Comment: Thanks for that w3fools link! +1

Comment: I was a little tempted to regard that as a spam post.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
var str  = "Visit W3Fools 45PL";          // should match this
var str1 = "Visit W3Fools 45PL Other";    // should NOT match this
var str2 = "Any Random value 133PL"       // should match this
var str3 = "Any Random value 133Pl"       // should NOT match this

var test  = "Visit W3Fools 4X5";              // should match this
var test1 = "Visit W3Fools 4X5PL Other";      // should NOT match this
var test2 = "Any Random value 13.270X46.96";  // should match this
var test3 = "Any Random value 13.21X12.36 ";  // should NOT match this, as last word is white space

var patt1 = /\s\d+PL$/;

document.write( patt1 + ' =~ "' + str + '" => ' + patt1.test(str) + '<br>');
document.write( patt1 + ' =~ "' + str1 + '" => ' + patt1.test(str1) + '<br>');
document.write( patt1 + ' =~ "' + str2 + '" => ' + patt1.test(str2) + '<br>');
document.write( patt1 + ' =~ "' + str3 + '" => ' + patt1.test(str3) + '<br>');

var patt2 = /\s\d+(?:[.]\d+)?X\d+(?:[.]\d+)?$/;

document.write( patt2 + ' =~ "' + test + '" => ' + patt2.test(test) + '<br>');
document.write( patt2 + ' =~ "' + test1 + '" => ' + patt2.test(test1) + '<br>');
document.write( patt2 + ' =~ "' + test2 + '" => ' + patt2.test(test2) + '<br>');
document.write( patt2 + ' =~ "' + test3 + '" => ' + patt2.test(test3) + '<br>');
```

The page writes out as:

```
/\s\d+PL$/ =~ "Visit W3Fools 45PL" => true
/\s\d+PL$/ =~ "Visit W3Fools 45PL Other" => false
/\s\d+PL$/ =~ "Any Random value 133PL" => true
/\s\d+PL$/ =~ "Any Random value 133Pl" => false
/\s\d+(?:[.]\d+)?X\d+(?:[.]\d+)?$/ =~ "Visit W3Fools 4X5" => true
/\s\d+(?:[.]\d+)?X\d+(?:[.]\d+)?$/ =~ "Visit W3Fools 4X5PL Other" => false
/\s\d+(?:[.]\d+)?X\d+(?:[.]\d+)?$/ =~ "Any Random value 13.270X46.96" => true
/\s\d+(?:[.]\d+)?X\d+(?:[.]\d+)?$/ =~ "Any Random value 13.21X12.36 " => false
```