# what's wrong with this regular expression (if else regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want is, there is a textbox with maximum length of 5. The values allowed are..

1. any integer // for example 1, 3, 9, 9239 all are valid
2. real number, with exaclty one point after decimal // eg. 1.2, 93.7 valid and 61.37, 55.67 invalid
3. it is also allowed to enter only decimal and a digit after that, that is .7 is valid entry (would be considered as 0.7)

I found this page, http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html
So what I thought is that

1. There is a digit
2. If there is a digit and a decimal after that, there must be one number after that
3. If there is no digit there must be a decimal and a digit after that

So, the regex I made is..

```
a single digit one or more => /d+  
an optional decimal point followed by exactly one digit => (?:[.]\d{1})?  
if first condition matches => (?(first condition) => (?((?<=\d+)  
then, match the option decimal and one exact digit =>(?((?<=\d+)(?:[.]\d{1})?  
else => |
find if there is a decimal and one exact digit => (?:[.]\d{1}){1}  
check the whole condition globally => /gm
```

overall expression =>

```
(?(?<=\d+)(?:[.]\d{1}){1}|(?:[.]\d{1}){1})+/gm
```

But it doesn't outputs anything..
Here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Fs6aq/4/

ps: the pattern1 and pattern2 there, are related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656750/regular-expression-for-given-pattern).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Fs6aq/5/ You forget a `/` in your example, that's why it is not working.

Comment: Please notice that JavaScript regexes do not support lookbehind.

Comment: @Bergi: Finally! The reason why its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following pattern:

```
/^\d{0,4}\.?\d$/
```

It seems to fulfil all your requirements:

```
> /^\d{0,4}\.?\d$/.test(".4")
  true
> /^\d{0,4}\.?\d$/.test(".45")
  false
> /^\d{0,4}\.?\d$/.test("1234.4")
  true
> /^\d{0,4}\.?\d$/.test("12345.4")
  false
> /^\d{0,4}\.?\d$/.test("12345")
  true
> /^\d{0,4}\.?\d$/.test("123456")
  false
```

This pattern assumes that the number can have a maximum of five digits and an optional decimal point.

If the maximum length of five includes the optional decimal point then the pattern is slightly more complex:

```
/^(?:\d{1,5}|\d{0,3}\.\d)$/
```

The first part of the group deals with integer numbers of the required length, the second option of the group deals with real numbers which maximum length (including the decimal point) is five.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are complicating things too much. I did a quick test and unless I'm missing something this regex seems to work fine:

```
/^\d*\.?\d$/
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/esihex/4/edit

**Edit:** To check the length you can do it without regex:

```
if ( value.replace('.','').length <= 5 && regex.test( value ) ) {
  ...
}
```

Notice that I used `replace` to remove the dots so they don't count as characters when getting the length.

Comment: In your example, `.7` returns `false`, which should be `true` according to what he wants.

Comment: Mmmm, `.7` returns true, If trailing zeroes are allowed it would be as easy as `/^\d*\.?\d0*$/`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
var checkedString = "45.3 fsd fsd fsdfsd 673.24 fsd63.2ds 32.2 ds  32 ds 44 fasd 432 235f d653 dsdfs";
checkedString = " "+checkedString;
var results = checkedString.match(/[\s]{1}(\d+\.*\d{1})(?![\d\.\w])+/gm);
results.map(function(result) {
    return result.trim();
});
```

Couldn't make it in other way because in JS `(?<=` (lookbehind) regexp is not working.

This will be returned:

```
["45.3","32.2","32","44","432"]
```

So probably it's what you've expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do with those conditionals in your regex. I also looked at your jsfiddle, which outputs nothing for me. But I made a two versions of a regex that matches the correct values for the textbox, which are `^(?!(.{6,}))(?:[1-9]\d*)*(?:\.\d*[1-9])?$` and `^(?!(.{6,}))(?:\d*)*(?:\.\d*)?$`.

The first disallows to start with zero, or end with zero after the decimal.

Comment if you need explanation of the regex.